# How do I avoid changing ever stylesheet if I change my menu bar width?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for a friend and have a side navigation bar and a top menu/banner which I've put into a header file and plan to include for each page.

I've created the scales using values in CSS:

```
    .nav-bar {
      width:100px;
      left: 0px;
    }
```

I've not done much web development, I'm a C++ developer through and through so forgive my inexperience. But if I'm going to use this nav bar on every page, then I can offset the content by 100px for each page no problem, until it comes to changing the width. I'd have to change all of my stylesheets to reflect this. What's the correct way to set it up so I don't have to change them all?

Many thanks,
Pete

Comment: your question isn't very clear, changing the width where ? if it's site wide then you only have to change it in the one stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Include the same stylesheet externally, with a `<link>` element in the header, on every page.